# How can select all input elements through css?

Tags: html, css, forms, css-selectors, frontend

The below css code are repeating is there any css shortcut so we can select all input field in single line of code.

```
.form-group input[type='text'],
.form-group input[type='email'],
.form-group input[type='password'],
.form-group input[type='tel']  
{
   margin:10px; 
}
```

Comment: **All** inputs?  Then just `input {your css values}`

Comment: The current css that you have is in a single line and all the input elements shares 1 css property as it is. Not sure what you mean by turning it into 1 line.

Comment: The only way is to add another class on the input `.form-group input.myclass` but i don't think is a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your HTML structure is something as follows:

```
<div class="form-group"> // or any other kind of wrapper element with a class of "form-group"
  <input type="text">
  <input type="email">
  <input type="pasword">
  <input type="tel">
</div>
```

You can just replace your current css with the following:

```
.form-group input { margin:10px; }
```

And the margin will be applied to all of your `<input>` elements nested inside your `.form-group` element.

Check and run the following Code Snippet for a practical example of the above code:

```css
.form-group input { margin:10px; }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="email">
  <input type="pasword">
  <input type="tel">
</div>
```

Comment: This misses <select> and <textarea> elements. Yes, this is a pedantic point if you take "all input elements" to mean literally and only <input> elements.